# showing 0,00 amount to be Stripe

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe , where the users are subscribing to a paid different plans for one payment. The payments are successfully made, but the main problem is that during the 3D Secure payment process (we are operating in Europe, where 3DS payment checks are mandatory), the amount that is shown to the user is 0,00. Which is not only incorrect, but more importantly, confusing to the person about to making the payment

```
     public function purchase(Request $request, Plan $plan)
{

            $user = $request->user();
            $paymentMethod = $request->input('payment_method');
            $encryptedSystemId = $request->input('system_id');
            $encryptedBoxId = $request->input('box_id');
            
            // Decrypt the encrypted IDs
            $systemId = Crypt::decrypt($encryptedSystemId);
            $boxId = Crypt::decrypt($encryptedBoxId);
            
            // Validate the IDs and user authorization
            $system = System::findOrFail($systemId);
            $box = Box::findOrFail($boxId);
            $total = $plan->price;
            

         
   

    try {
        $user->createOrGetStripeCustomer();
        $user->updateDefaultPaymentMethod($paymentMethod);
        $user->charge($total * 100, $paymentMethod, [
            'metadata' =>
            ['system_id' => $systemId, 
            'box_id' => $boxId,
            'tenant_id '=> $user->tenant->id,
            ]
           ]); // * 100 because Stripe deals with cents
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        return back()->with('error', 'Error processing payment: ' . $exception->getMessage());
    }






<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script>
    let stripe = Stripe("{{ env('STRIPE_KEY') }}")
    let elements = stripe.elements()
    let style = {
        base: {
            color: '#32325d',
            fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
            fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
            fontSize: '16px',
            '::placeholder': {
                color: '#aab7c4'
            }
        },
        invalid: {
            color: '#fa755a',
            iconColor: '#fa755a'
        }
    }
    let card = elements.create('card', {
        style: style
    })
    card.mount('#card-element')
    let paymentMethod = null
    $('.card-form').on('submit', function(e) {
        $('#pay-btn').attr('disabled', true)
        if (paymentMethod) {
            return true
        }
        stripe.confirmCardSetup(
            "{{ $intent->client_secret }}", {
                payment_method: {
                    card: card,
                    billing_details: {
                        name: $('.card_holder_name').val()
                    }
                }
            }
        ).then(function(result) {
            if (result.error) {
                toastr.error(
                    '__("rental.The data you entered contains errors! Review 
              it and try again")')
                $('#pay-btn').removeAttr('disabled')
            } else {
                paymentMethod = result.setupIntent.payment_method
                $('.payment-method').val(paymentMethod)
                $('.card-form').submit()
                $('span.icon').removeAttr('hidden');
                $('#pay-btn').attr('disabled', true)
            }
        })
        return false
    })


  <div class="tab-content mt-4 " id="card-tab" style="display:none">
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('rentals.purchase', $plan) }}"
     class="card-form mt-3 mb-3">
       @csrf
        <input type="hidden" name="payment_method" class="payment-method">        
       <input type="hidden" name="system_id" value="{{ encrypt($system->id) }}">
       <input type="hidden" name="box_id" value="{{ encrypt($box->id) }}">

         <div class="mb-4">
         <input class="StripeElement form-input px-4 py-3 rounded-lg w-full"
          name="card_holder_name" placeholder="{{ __('rental.Cardholder 
             Name') }}">
                 </div>
             <div>
            <div id="card-element"></div>
              </div>
              <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
               <div class="mt-3 text-center">
             <button type="submit" class="bg-red-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded" id="pay-btn">{{ __('rental.Pay') }} {{ $plan->price }} &euro; <span  class="icon" hidden><i class="fas fa-sync fa-spin"></i></span></button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>



and this when I debug 
 #_originalValues: array:39 [▼
      "id" => "pi_3NZqdIC6ZwDjQHNX1R7KJLoO"
      "object" => "payment_intent"
      "amount" => 100
      "amount_capturable" => 0
      "amount_details" => array:1 [▼
        "tip" => []
      ]
      "amount_received" => 100
```

Comment: Please only add the relevant tags. This issue has nothing to do with `stripe`, why bother adding the code for the stripe integration, when clearly the problem you described has nothing to do with it? "*the amount that is shown to the user is 0,00*"

Comment: And, in addition to the comment above, please format your code properly so that is easily readable. Don't just throw some unformatted lines on us and expect us to solve your problem...

Comment: no
During the checkout process, when I proceed to the verification page, the payment amount is displayed as 0.00. However, after completing the verification process, Stripe charges the correct amount. If anyone has experienced a similar issue or has any suggestions for a solution, I would be grateful for your assistance. How can I resolve this problem and ensure that the correct payment amount is displayed throughout the entire checkout process?

when the customer pay every is right 
but when show the 3d bank show 0.00

Comment: "*when I proceed to the verification page*" - You mean, the customer is already on stripe's platform?

Answer (score 2):

Based off the code you've provided, you're using SetupIntents to collect the payment method details. SetupIntents are used to collect payment method details for future use : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse. It's expected that if 3DS is required, it's for 0,00 since you aren't charging the card for any amount at the point of payment method collection.

If you're using Subscriptions, you should be following this guide : https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements to collect and save the payment method at the time of payment.

If you're using one-time payments, then you can collect and save the payment method details at the same time payment is being made : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment

Comment: this is laravel
we use for one payments
 try {
        $user->createOrGetStripeCustomer();
        $user->updateDefaultPaymentMethod($paymentMethod);
       dd($user->charge($total * 100, $paymentMethod, [
            'metadata' =>
            ['system_id' => $systemId, 
            'box_id' => $boxId,
            'tenant_id '=> $user->tenant->id,
            ]
           ])); // * 100 because Stripe deals with cents
           
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        return back()->with('error', 'Error processing payment: ' . $exception->getMessage());
    }

Comment: every is work and pay 
but when show the bank 3d card show the amount 0.00